# Router + file server build

Tags: networking, router, samba, computer-building, hardware-rec

I am trying to build an always-on router + file server system that will serve as a (wired) router and as a file server that I will access from my two Windows (7/XP) machines. I am not worried about power consumption or the ambient noise resulting from this build. My main criteria are budget (under $150) and to protect my data in case my cheap-o components bite the dust. Also, in this project, I am roughly [following advice here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71S9fek0FKA).

In fact, I think I will be running the Smoothwall software that he uses. In case it is relevant, I am situated in a University LAN and I believe we get assigned static IPs by the DHCP server.

The main components of this build will be the following:

1. Chip: Some of the feedback for this product says that it is possible to unlock another core on some motherboards - will this be possible on the motherboard that I intend to use below? Is it advisable for the purposes of this build?

   [AMD Sempron 145 Sargas 2.8GHz Socket AM3 45W Single-Core Desktop Processor](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103888)

   Price: $40
2. MoBo: My main concern for the motherboard is whether it will be able to handle some sort of RAID configuration (I know nothing about RAID, or backups). The other idea that I have is to have a second HDD which is periodically backed up with cron jobs.

   [BIOSTAR N68S3+ AM3 NVIDIA MCP68S Micro ATX AMD Motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813138293)

   Price: $45
3. Memory: 2gb of memory should be enough, I think. Is this the right memory for this motherboard?

   [Kingston HyperX Blu 2GB 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820104219)

   Price: $14
4. Case: This is a micro-ATX case and comes with 400W PSU.

   [iMicro ATX Micro Tower Case](http://amzn.com/B005CUVORQ)

   Price: $23
5. HDD: I have a 5400rpm 120gb IDE HDD refurbished HDD that I bought off newegg for $18. I could get another one in case I need to for a backup.
6. NIC+sundry: [Rosewill RC-402 LAN Card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833166004) 10/ 100Mbps PCI for $7, throw in some ethernet cables and a [Netgear metal switch](http://amzn.com/B00002EQCW) for $10.

This brings the build cost up to about $160.

My concern now is that all the components are compatible with each other and will fit into the case that I have chosen (I don't have a lot of experience building PCs). Also, any advice about the best strategy for having a continuous backup of my file server which is easily restorable will be greatly appreciated.

---

So I did some additional googling and I was hoping that the Smoothwall Linux distro would allow me to have Samba to run my file server, but [some advice seems to suggest otherwise](http://forums.overclockers.com.au/showthread.php?t=149463).

So, I am throwing in the question of what distro will allow me to run a router AND a file server together.

Comment: Sorry about the way I have included URLs; I wasn't allowed to include more than two URLs.

Comment: Most of your hardware looks fine to me, though, i'd really not like to rely on refurbished IDE drives running anything close to critical. Sata Drives, though not nearly as cheap would be somewhat more trustworthy. It sort of distracts from what seems to be the real question to me, to do with running a router and a fileserver

Comment: I did insert your links, but essentially, this is nothing but a shopping recommendation question, which are off topic on our site for various reasons, one being that this is too localized to your situation and won't help future visitors at all, sorry. I think we have enough questions on about which RAM will fit which MB. Plus, you're asking a lot of questions at one. Backup strategies, the software you want to run, et cetera. It'd be more constructive to break this apart into separate questions (as long as they comply to our [FAQ]).

Comment: Well, the shopping list gives context to my two main queries - what components are needed for a backup setup which is very relevant for building a file server, and the part about the linux distro since the router and file server need work concurrently. Thanks for prettify-ing my post. :)

Comment: The components bit is sort of detracting from the other part i think. It'll all work, unless something is broken ;p

Comment: As @JourneymanGeek said, I think you're fine (Journeyman Geek, you want to verify? I'm not a hardware specialist) – and then you could just take that out of your question :)

Comment: Well, right kind of ram for the system, there's support for the legacy IDE hard drives, and matx motherboard is on a matx case. The only possible concern i'd have is that many cheap PSUs may not have PATA/Molex power connector, but there's no way to check before you get it. [The standalone PSU by the same company seems to have them](http://www.amazon.com/iMicro-IM400W-ATX12V-Power-Supply/dp/B002HREGRM) but YMMV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much any distro will do what you want to do, its just a matter of setting up the right packages. There's a pretty comprehensive guide on [debian's webpage on one such setup](http://wiki.debian.org/green/Router) and [another simpler one here](http://blog.noviantech.com/2010/12/22/debian-router-gateway-in-15-minutes/).You should be able to do this on any other distro, with equivalent packages.

Basically you're setting up your network interfaces to do what they need to do (talk to wan, talk to lan, get an ip address off wan, broadcast the fact that its a server on lan)  [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) to handle dhcp and dns stuff, then set up file sharing as per normal.

Run your favoured flavour of filesharing on top of that (such as samba), and it'll likely be a lot easier than trying to run it off a router centric distro.

In this particular case i'd probably suggest keeping the OS and data seperate (In this case, maybe running the OS off a usb key for example), and running periodic backups over rsync.

I'd also recommend looking at file system overlays that do replication - [grayhole](http://www.greyhole.net/)  is a rather interesting option that allows dissimilar hard disks to be used. You could then rsync files for periodic backups offsite.

Comment: Ok, so this is some great advice. I guess the Smoothwall things was mainly to keep the system light and problem-free. I could use some stripped down Linux distro. This greyhole thing sounds superb - so I throw in a bunch of HDDs into my server and it uses the free space on all of them to keep spare copies? And if one of the HDDs fails, the algorithm is such that the entire data is always recoverable?

Comment: yup.Greyhole pretty much that, and it works on top of whatever file systems those drives have. Router distros are nice for embedded, uber low end hardware, but if you're willing to put in the effort, a full linux distro probably will be easier in terms of hardware requirements and software setup. The main thing you give up with debian vs a router distro is a web ui